# Get second last word from string using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I need to get the second last word from a string value.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["sample text 1 AFTEDGH XX"],
  ["sample text 2 GDHDH ZZ"],
  ["sample text 3 JEYHEHH YY"],
  ["sample text 4 QPRYRT EB"],
  ["sample text 5 KENBFBF XX"]
]).toDF("line")

+--------+
|word    |
+--------+
|AFTEDGH |
|GDHDH   |
|JEYHEHH |
|QPRYRT  |
|KENBFBF |
+--------+
```

I tried:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('word', F.split(F.col('line'), ' ')[-2])

df_new = df.withColumn('word', F.reverse(F.split(F.col('line'), ' '))[-2])
```

But they return Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use negative indices, you can use `element_at`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('word', F.element_at(F.split(F.col('line'), ' '), -2))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------+-------+
|line                    |word   |
+------------------------+-------+
|sample text 1 AFTEDGH XX|AFTEDGH|
|sample text 2 GDHDH ZZ  |GDHDH  |
|sample text 3 JEYHEHH YY|JEYHEHH|
|sample text 4 QPRYRT EB |QPRYRT |
|sample text 5 KENBFBF XX|KENBFBF|
+------------------------+-------+
```

Your second attempt is almost correct - just use a positive index because you have reversed the array already, and remember to subtract 1 from the index as well:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('word', F.reverse(F.split(F.col('line'), ' '))[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `substring_index` function :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "word",
    F.substring_index(F.substring_index("line", " ", -2), " ", 1)
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------+-------+
#|line                    |word   |
#+------------------------+-------+
#|sample text 1 AFTEDGH XX|AFTEDGH|
#|sample text 2 GDHDH ZZ  |GDHDH  |
#|sample text 3 JEYHEHH YY|JEYHEHH|
#|sample text 4 QPRYRT EB |QPRYRT |
#|sample text 5 KENBFBF XX|KENBFBF|
#+------------------------+-------+
```